# How to set to Webform's fields a 'Number of values' setting like in default content types?

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

Yeah, so in content type fields like Article or any other when you add a field it has an option 'Number of values' and if you select Unlimited it adds a button 'Add another item' when creating a content.

So I was thinking is it possible to do that with Webform module's forms? Let's say a user is filling in the form, let's say he fills in his phone number into Phone number field and then maybe he has a another phone number, so he could click 'Add another item' and that would open up a second field of a Phone Number field.

To be exact, I need that Unlimited option to work on Webform fieldset fields. So if I have a fieldset of three fields, I can click 'add another item' and it opens up a 2nd fieldset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Webform Addmore](http://drupal.org/project/webform_addmore)

> Webform Add More enables selected fieldsets to be initially hidden and
>   progressively shown with an Add more button, mimicking CCK multiple
>   fields. The approach was proposed by Bartezz, and code originally
>   implemented by span and kranklin [1](http://drupal.org/project/webform_addmore). This module adds a checkbox
>   setting to webform fieldset components to select which should have Add
>   more functionality, as well as an advanced setting to override the
>   button label per Webform.

Comment: Doesn't really work like I was expecting. I have two different fieldsets and I want them both to have let's say number of values = 20. So when I enable both of them 'Add More fieldset' it hides my 2nd form and gives me that Add more button which brings the hidden form up. It also gives me an error: Notice: Undefined index: label in webform_addmore_form_alter() (line 93 of /sites/all/modules/webform_addmore/webform_addmore.module).

Answer (score 0):

This functionality unfortunately doesn't exist yet. You can read this thread: https://drupal.org/node/354381 which has some hacks/work-arounds that might suit your needs (including the Webform Add More module solution from Mohammed Shameem's response. You may want to subscribe to this thread to be informed if/when the functionality becomes available.